# Como esvaziar buffer do php durante execução?

Tags: php, buffer

Quero que seja impresso algo na tela durante a execução, e não somente quando o script terminar, tentei:

```
<?php

ob_start();

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){

   echo $i . '<br>';
   ob_flush();
   flush();

   sleep(3);
}
```

mas não funcionou, tudo é impresso de uma vez ao termino da execução.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com os meus testes, dessa forma funciona:

```
@ini_set("output_buffering", 0);  // off 
@ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 0);  // off
@ini_set("implicit_flush", 1);  // on   

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

ob_implicit_flush(true);

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {

    echo $i;

    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

    sleep(1);
}
```

Tirei dessa resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978809/3096922)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Exatamente isso que preciso.